# How to make custom GPT read information in uploaded files on WordPress website via Actions/API?

Tags: openai-api, wordpress-rest-api, chatgpt-api

How do I make my custom GPT read information in uploaded files on my WordPress website via WordPress REST API and custom GPT Actions?

So I have uploaded PDF files on my WordPress website. I built a custom GPT on ChatGPT. I want to use Actions in my customGPT to connect it to my WordPress website so that the GPT can output information with my website’s information as a knowledge source.

Is this technically feasible?